# Powershell - use multiple predetermined arguments

Tags: powershell

Short version: is it possible to pass multiple predefined arguments to a powershell function/commandlet?

Since I am not sure about the terms, I cannot find an answer to this. So here is the example, I am using Exchange 2013 Powershell commands:

```
Get-MoveRequest -MoveStatus Queued
```

This will give me alle mailbox move requests that are currently queued but not yet processed.

```
Get-MoveRequest -MoveStatus InProcess
```

This will give you all mailbox move requests that are processed at the moment and not yet finished.

The arguments `InProcess` and `Queued` are predefined by the function. Is there any way to use `InProcess` and `Queued` in just one command? I know that I can run two commands and concenate the output, but I am curious if it is possible to use multiple of these predefined arguments at once. <s>So the question is not Exchange specific, I want to know if Powershell can handle multiple predefined arguments as a commandlet parameter.</s>

The Get-MoveRequest documentation does not state if or if not the MoveStatus parameter allows multiple values as argument.

- Is this possible?
- What is the correct syntax to test this, in case that the parameter allows mutli-value arguments?

Comment: This question is going to need to be answered for each command, not at the PowerShell level.  For instance, if Get-MoveRequest only allows a single value for the -MoveStatus parameter, PowerShell can't do anything different.

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic here (see [help/on-topic]). However, a workaround could be  something like `'Queued', 'InProcess' | Foreach-Object { Get-MoveRequest -MoveStatus $_ }`. And yes, Powershell can handle multiple predefined arguments as a _particular_ cmdlet parameter, see e.g. [`Get-ChildItem -Attributes`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7#parameters). Always check the docs.

Comment: @JosefZ I don't see how this is off-topic - would be glad if you explained.
I checked the docs of Get-MoveRequest, but there was no information about this. Obviously "no Information" means "No" when it comes to Microsoft Docs.

Comment: @Tobias _Server Fault is for questions about **managing information technology systems in a business environment**._  Your question _"… is not Exchange specific, I want to know if Powershell can handle …"_ Blatantly off-topic being about _common_ Powershell features.

Comment: @JosefZ So powershell questions without specific business environment modules (AD, Exchange...) are off-topic here? I find a lot of high-voted powershell questions here that are not about business-specific modules. But I will change the question to Exchange specific, since this is what I am looking for at the moment.

Comment: Here's an example in [New-MoveRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/move-and-migration/new-moverequest) cmdlet, parameter `-InternalFlags` allows `[-InternalFlags <InternalMrsFlag[]>]` i.e. an array (`[]`) of (predefined) values from the [InternalMrsFlag enumeration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-api/dn754411(v%3Dexchg.150)).  One can see the contrast to `Get-MoveRequest` where the `-MoveStatus` parameter pattern is `[-MoveStatus <RequestStatus>]` i.e. a single value from _RequestStatus Enum_ (no `[]` array of).